# is 0 in the solution of the problem 4.10 of enderton's set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

### definition of inductive closure on $A$ under $f:B\to B$

let $f$ be a function from $B$ into $B$, and $A\subseteq B$.

- definition by the intersection of all inductive sets.
  $$
  C^* = \bigcap \lbrace X\mid A\subseteq X\subseteq B \land f[X]\subseteq X \rbrace.
  $$
- definition by the union of all results got from recursion.
  $$
  h(0)= A\\
  h(n^+) = h(n) \cup f[h(n)]\\
  C_*=\bigcup {\mathop{\rm ran}} h =\bigcup_{i\in \omega}h(i).
  $$
- both definitions are coincident with each other. ($C^* = C_*$)

### exercise 4.10

assume that $B$ is the set of real numbers, $f(x) = x^2$, and $A$ is the closed interval $\left[\cfrac{1}{2},1\right]$. what is the set called $C^*$ and $C_*$?

### my solution.

I thought the solution is $\bigcup_{n\in \omega}\left[\cfrac{1}{2^{n+1}},1\right]$ and I think it's $(0,1]$.

but other solution told me the solution is $[0,1]$.

but I think it's odd, because we are not using the concept of limit like calculus.

I explain why I thought like this.

I think we only have to check the case if $f(x) = x\cdot x$ for $x\in S =\lbrace z \mid \exists n\in\omega, z = \cfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}\rbrace$.

${\rm ran}(f\upharpoonright S)$ does not have the member 0, I try to prove it by induction.

when we choose $x=\cfrac{1}{2}$, $x\cdot x= \cfrac{1}{4}$ so it is not $0$.

and if we assume $f(x)$ is not zero if $x = \cfrac{1}{2^{n}}$ for arbitrary fixed $n$, in the case $x = \cfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ likewise $f(x)$ is not zero because $x=\cfrac{1}{2^n}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\neq 0$ and $x\cdot x$ is likewise not zero.

so how many times when we choose $n\in\omega$, we can't get $0$ so $0$ is not a value of $f$.

so I think $0\notin {\rm ran}h$.

is my inference correct?